# MariaDB Galera ? Percona ? DRBD ? Why not simple replication?

Tags: mysql, database-replication, mariadb, percona, drbd

I need redundant Mariadb or Mysql solution, i tested :

Mysql + DRDB + Pacemaker (currently in production)
Mariadb Galera
Percona XtraDB

I need a solution that goes everywhere and Percona and Mariadb need Innodb engine for replication. I found DRBD solution to heavy... I hope there is easy solution...

And i don't need "LB > Master / Master" solution, i need security not performance ! I think going to the replication but i never design replication structure for MariaDB / Mysql, i don't know the issues in production.

It's viable for "LB > Master / Slave" therefore without VIP ? What happens when master come back after one day down ? Compatibilty for Myisam and Innodb with no problem ?

Comment: I use MariaDB with galera replication in multiple environments for redundancy and load balancing and it works well and is easy to manage.  Yes you have to use InnoDB tables, but do you really need other tables types?

Comment: I can't control what is installed by my clients. Most of my clients do not understand why they should migrate innodb if their script is  installed with Myisam. How can I controlling this? Force Innodb only for my client ?

Comment: That could be problematic.  You can't disable MyISAM but you can make InnoDB the default engine by setting `default_storage_engine=InnoDB`.

Comment: Why "mysql" table work with myisam ? I can't replicate this table on my cluster Mariadb Galera for replicate user create / privilege ?

Comment: Why mysql table is on MyISAM when after Mariadb Galera installation ? http://reho.st/self/c24178308c827678b54200349b8145d1ba7a78f0.png

Comment: MariaDB supports MyISAM tables but they are not replicated by galera by default since galera requires a transactional storage engine which MyISAM is not.  There is an option `wsrep_replicate_myisam` that will cause galera to replicate MyISAM tables as well as it can, but since MyISAM is not really supported it is not reliable.